# Why this folder structre breaking my NodeJs code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I built a node js project and later tried to re arrange the code to make the folder structure according to my newer requirements.

**older structure**

```
|-controller
|   |--docController.js
|-index.js
```

**newer file structure**

```
|-adapter/express
|  |--controller
|     |---docController.js
|-route
|  |--docRoute.js
|-frameworks
|  |--app.js
|  |--server.js
```

with the new structure i had to make few changes inside the code like separating routes from index.js to a dedicated route.js. splitted index.js into server and app.js

now my server is running but whenever i hit my api it isn't able to locate the routes.

**App.js**

```
const docRoutes = require('./../adapters/express/routes/docRoutes');

const app = express();

app.use('/', docRoutes);
// app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
//     next(new AppError(`Can't find ${req.originalUrl} on this server!`, 404));
//   });

module.exports = app;
```

**server.js**

```
const app = require('./app');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config({ path: './../config.env' });

const port = process.env.PORT;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
  });

  process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
    console.log('UNHANDLED REJECTION!  Shutting down...');
    console.log(err.name, err.message);
    server.close(() => {
      process.exit(1);
    });
  });
```

**docController.js**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config({ path: './../../../config.env' });
SOME CONST VARIABLES FROM dotenv

const fs = require('fs')


function findValueByKey(obj, targetKey) {
  SOME BORING CODE
}

exports.getAccessToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  SOME BORING CODE
}

FOLLOWED BY FEW EXPORTED FUNCTIONS
```

**docRoutes.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const docController = require('./../controllers/docController');

const router = express.Router();


router.get('/get',docController.getAccessToken);
router.post('/create',docController.getAccessToken,docController.createDoc);
router.post('/submit',docController.getAccessToken,docController.addTagsAndSend);
router.get('/preview',docController.getAccessToken,docController.previewDoc);

module.exports = router;
```

the code was working earlier but now it's somewhere breaking between app and routes. Can someone who's experienced with Node js locate the problem?

Comment: Try `app.use(docRoutes);` – I'd suspect you're dealing with double slashes...

Comment: i did but the same response <body>
 <pre>Cannot GET /create</pre>
</body>

Comment: Well, you don't have a GET handler for `/create`, do you?  Try `GET`ting `/get`...

Comment: It would be helpful if you past the EXACT error it produces.

Comment: yes, I was trying to find this for hours but it never occured to me that the response itself is screaming for the solution. thanks AKX and DanteTheSmith for your valuable time :)

Comment: Uh */adapters/express/routes/docRoutes* does not exist in your newer file structure?

Answer (score 0):

turns out there was no get handler for /create.  I just had to hit it as a post call and it started working